# How to fix Error: W083

Tags: javascript

How to fix `Error: W083` in the following code?

I tried a few things but then my function is not working.

```
new google.maps.event.addListener(location[i].holdMarker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(location[i].contentString);
        infowindow.open(map,this);
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (windowWidth <= 1080) {
            map.setZoom(13);
        } else if (windowWidth > 1080) {
            map.setZoom(14);  
        }
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        location[i].picBoolTest = true;
    }; 
})(location[i].holdMarker, i));

//Loads the infoWindow when a item is selected fron nav list
var searchNav = $('#nav' + i);
searchNav.click((function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(location[i].contentString);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        map.setZoom(14);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        location[i].picBoolTest = true;
     }; 
})(location[i].holdMarker, i));
```

Comment: which line is giving the error? does the error say more than just W083?

Comment: oh, that's a js(l|h)int error? about making functions in a loop?

Comment: yes....declaring a function in loop.can you please help

Comment: As there is no loop in the code you posted it's hard to tell you what to do